# How can I associate an SSL certificate with Bluemix custom domains?

Tags: ssl, ibm-cloud

When I try to upload an SSL certificate for my Bluemix custom domain, I receive this error message:

```
BXNUI2072E: The intended host name, *.<custom_domain>, is not a subject within the certificate.
```

How can I go about getting my certificate uploaded successfully and avoid this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I learned that the problem here was due to the certificate I was using, which was for a single, specific domain. Bluemix supports only wildcard certificates, that's a key point.

I got around this by replacing my single domain certificate with a wildcard certificate.

To generate a wildcard certificate, I needed to specify a wildcard domain by adding an asterisk (*) and a period (.) in front of my custom domain name.

In the example that follows I used OpenSSL to generate a self-signed wildcard certificate. I've generalized the example but simply specify a wildcard domain for the Common Name field.

```
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:*.<custom_domain>
```

I tested and succesfully got this to work for both a self-signed certificate and a certificate signed by a certificate authority.

Comment: Using *.<custom_domain> while creating the cert did not work.